Create string of text with Textjoin, dependent on a selection from DropDown
I need to populate a cell with a string (textjoin?). The string should contain the unique Price Art. And its percentage of the total, from columns, dependent on a selection made in a drop down list.

I have a limited different "Type of work": PM, Engineering, Enabling works...
I have 1-4 supplier quotes
Each supplier quotes will be broken down into "Type of Works" and Price Art. (Price Art will differ in code and number)



Input the name of a supplier
Based on the quote, for each Type of work, break the Cost down into Price Art.
Type of work in Col. A,
Cost in Col C,
Price Art. in Col D
Repeat from 1 for next Supplier...
When all quotes are done - The "tool" should, dependent on the Supplier selected, create a string for each "Type of work", with the percentage of the total for each Price art. and Type of works..

A11 - A18 - A... : Input the Type of Works (Drop-Down list connected to C1:K1
C9: First supplier name
E9: Second supplier name...
C11 - C18 - C...: Input the Cost for Supplier one, according to the Type of work, and Price Art., obs Type of works can have different price Art.
Repeat for all columns - E-J....
C2:K2 : For the selected Supplier in B2, and all Unique "Type of works" in Col A, calculate the % for each price art of the Type of work... (See C2)


=LET(range,A9:G18,
     c,CHOOSECOLS,
     d,DROP,
     u,UNIQUE,
     header,d(TAKE(range,1),,-1),
     h,TOCOL(header,1),
     data,d(range,1),
     f,LAMBDA(a,b,FILTER(a,header=b)),
     j,TOROW(u(c(data,1))),
HSTACK(u(TOCOL(h)),
       REDUCE(u(d(j,,1),,1),d(h,1),LAMBDA(k,l,
       VSTACK(k,
              MAP(d(j,,1),LAMBDA(m,
                  LET(g,GROUPBY(f(d(data,,1),l),f(d(data,,-1),l),PERCENTOF,,0,,c(data,1)=m),
TEXTJOIN("; ",,IFERROR(ROUND(c(g,2)*100,)&"% "&c(g,1),"-"))))))))))

Where range is your input range starting at column A from where your supplier data starts (including headers).
c is ETA to use the letter as the function CHOOSECOLS(), d for DROP() and u for UNIQUE().
header is taking the header values from the input range, excluding the final cell value (of merged cell).
h takes out the empty cells from headers.
data is your input range excluding the header row.
f is a FILTER function to filter input range a where the header value equals B2.
j is the first column values of data
g creates a percentage summary on filtered Price Artikel and it's Cost where the first column values from data equals the value of the header value in row 1.
Next the columns of g are concatenated and wrapped in TEXTJOIN for each Type of work using MAP and for each Name supplier using REDUCE.

Sample of data I used for testing, where supplier 1 and supplier 2 are merged cells:




A
B
C
D
E
F




9

Name supplier
Supplier 1

Supplier 2



10
Type of work
work description
cost
price artikel
cost
price artikel


11
PMT

100
aaa
23
aaa


12
PMT

50
sss
3465
sss


13
ENG

43
ddd
1234
ddd


14
Civil works

23
sss
5467
fff


15
Civil works

56
ddd
3453
qqq


16
Trials

234
qqq
3245
rrr


17
PMT

150
aaa
56
fff


18
PMT

75
ttt
456
ttt



EDIT: Here's a version that avoids the use of GROUPBY:
=LET(supplier,TOCOL(C9:J9,1),
     work,UNIQUE(TOROW(A11:A39,1),1),
VSTACK(HSTACK("Type of work:",work),
       HSTACK(supplier,
              DROP(REDUCE("",TOCOL(C9:J9,1),
                   LAMBDA(g,x,
                          VSTACK(g,
                                 MAP(UNIQUE(TOROW(A11:A39,1),1),
                              LAMBDA(y,
                                     LET(m,MATCH(x,C9:J9),
                                         p,FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(C11:J39,m+{1,0}),A11:A39=y),
                                         f,FILTER(p,TAKE(p,,1)<>""),
                                         t,TAKE(f,,1),
                                         n,DROP(f,,1),
                                         u,UNIQUE(t),
                                     IFERROR(TEXTJOIN("; ",,u&" "&ROUND(MAP(u,LAMBDA(v,SUM(n*(t=v))))/SUM(n)*100,)),
                                             ""))))))),
                   1))))


Hi! - and thanks for the reply! The formula doesn't wotk for me... I get a couple of errors.


It doesn't seem to work to use c, d and u. When I repleced them with the actual fucntion - I fixed the formula error...


All cells produce a "-". and all suppliers is shown.



https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1inQrIIyLxJOZ0XviH8grPgOA6LgFFdgj/edit?usp=drive_link&ouid=107087365389671309304&rtpof=true&sd=true

I've added your formula in C3. The slightly changed formula in P9...

https://1drv.ms/x/c/c2332c47b39e641c/EdyiB6OtoaRChFzujOmo_pwBq9KxleBEFpzuNxezIYzN2w

Do you have access to groupby?

That is NOT a function I’ve seen before - can’t find it in my excel version 365…

That explains. Maybe you have the ability to upgrade your Excel.

Hi again! I will give it a try - but I found this on Microsoft: These functions are currently rolling out to users enrolled in the beta channel for Windows Excel and Mac Excel
New aggregation functions: GROUPBY and PIVOTBY - Microsoft Community Hub

By the way - I’m REALLY impressed with your knowledge of excel!!

Thanks. It's challenges like this that make me grow. I thought GROUPBY was now generally available in up-to-date versions

Hi Again... Your formula creates a Spill Array. This complicates it a bit, together with the GROUPBY that I can't get to work...  I do not need a Spill array - and it actually complicates it with a Spill array since I then need to filter out the result to get them into the correct cell... What I am looking for is to be able to select a Supplier from a drop down list, in my file in B2, and then present the corresponding text string in each cell: C1 to K1. MEaning that the result in C2 will be filtered on the data in B2 and C1, Result in D2 to be filtered on the data in B2 and D1...

Yes - this will requiere either a formula in all C2 to K2 cells - or a Spill array that corresponds to the data in C1 to K1. Would it be possible - without GROUPBY?

In the version log from MS I can see that GROUPBY was added in the 2409 update - I have the 2402 version... ! This means that I will have to ask the IT dep. to force/allow at least that version - and I really like that function! If I can learn to use it it looks to be very powerful!! - If I learn to use it...

See edit for a version that avoids GROUPBY. I think that should work for you. Let me know if it doesn't.
